# Native Error Code: 4. Out of memory while reading tuples

Tags: ssis-2012

I’m loading data from ODBC(32 bit) source(3M records) to OLEDB destination it is executing successfully in SSIS package. But throwing below error while executing from integration catalog. Kindly let me know how to resolve below error.

1.Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on ODBC Source returned error code 0x80004005.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure

2.: Open Database Connectivity (ODBC) error occurred. state: 'HY001'. Native Error Code: 4. Out of memory while reading tuples.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[Postgres ODBC Driver SSIS 32 Bit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EwmlA.png)

Setting the Declare/Fetch option ON and tweaking the Cache Size in your Postgres ODBC data source may help.

See:
https://www.simba.com/products/PostgreSQL/doc/ODBC_InstallGuide/win/content/odbc/re/options/ui/declarefetchmode.htm

Answer (score 0):

I am getting the same error pulling 2 million records from postgres using 32bit odbc driver with oledb ms sql destination. This is a memory leak in the VS debugger. All I can say at this point in testing is at 1.5 million rows and I don't get the error. Perhaps you have the 64 bit driver and the server has 32? In any case over 1.5million rows is asking for memory errors in this configuration